# Options for smart thermostats with a 2 wire gangbox

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I have baseboard heaters, and am interested in getting a smart thermostat like the [Mysa](https://shop.getmysa.com/products/mysa-baseboard).

My existing thermostats are 2 Ouellet OTH600s (similar to [this](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/773021/Ouellet-Oth550.html#manual)) and one [Honeywell Linevoltpro](https://www.honeywellhome.com/us/en/products/air/thermostats/programmable-thermostats/single-pole-line-voltage-programmable-thermostat-tl8130a1005-u/). These control my baseboard heaters which are a bunch of [Ouellet OFMs](https://www.ouellet.com/ouellet.com/files/8a/8a0b288a-9de0-41dc-9de3-2bce8db3696c.pdf): 1500, 2000, 2250, 2500

Looking at the gangboxes, they have 2 wires, which is apparently not compatible with the Mysa... or anything else.

[image]

What options do I have that would allow me to move to modern systems like Mysa?

It it possible to convert/upgrade/replace my existing wiring?

Is there some adaptor that works?

Comment: Can you post a closeup of what's going on with where the wires exit the left-hand box, and also a better view of the insides of the right-hand box please?